# Ignore ids that are listed in top

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have 3 tables:

```
Client1 ( id, Name)
Client2 ( id, Name)
Tasks (id, ClientType, ClientId, Task)
```

I need to get top (20) most used clients and tasks, and then I need to list all clients from client1 and client2 EXCEPT ids that are in top (20)

```
ClientType = 0 refers to Client1 table
ClientType = 1 refers to Client2 table
```

if there is just 5 different clients in Tasks than it will list those 5 clients and then the rest of them

Example:

```
ClientID ClientType Task
--------------------------
1        0          Task1
1        1          Task2
402      0          Taks6
200      0          Task44
2        1          Task7
```

---

the rest of clients from client1 and client2
all ids from client1 where id not in (1,402,200)
all ids from client2 where id not in (1,2)

I really hope I explained this issue well, this query is the basic on what I actually need but it's the main problem. I have made a query that lists top x most used clients and ALL clients from client1 and client2  but i can't make query that will ignore top x id's.

Comment: please show some sample data and show expected result

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is good, this query can make the job.

```
SELECT TOP(20) ClientID, ClientType 
FROM tblTasks
GROUP BY ClientID, ClientType
ORDER BY count(*) DESC
UNION
SELECT ClientID, 0
FROM client1
UNION
SELECT ClientID, 1
FROM client2
```

Comment: ty for reply, but, tblTasks doesn't have ALL clients from client1 and client2, if there is  30 clients in client1 and 50 clients in client2 i need to get 80 rows where top x are most used clients (in table Tasks) from client1 and client2 tables. Basically i should get same number of clients if i use union on client1 and client2 tables only with different order.

Comment: Ok, I've changed the query according to your comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
drop table #tblTop20
SELECT TOP(20) ClientID, ClientType, count(*)  as count1
into #tblTop20
FROM [dbo].[Tasks]
GROUP BY ClientID, ClientType
order by Count(*) Desc  

SELECT ClientID, ClientType , Count1 as rank 
FROM #tblTop20
UNION
SELECT ID, 0,0
FROM [dbo].Client1 where ID not in (
select ClientID from #tblTop20 where ClientType=0)
UNION
SELECT Id, 0,0
FROM [dbo].Client2 where ID not in (
select ClientID from #tblTop20 where ClientType=1)
order by 3 desc
```